# Segmentation Fault Passing Reference as Function Parameter

Tags: c++, reference, segmentation-fault, stack

With this block of code, I'm getting a segmentation fault as I try to pass the stack references to the transferStacks() method. Any help on understanding why this is would be helpful!

I could just get rid of the helper method and it should work, but I'm trying to understand conceptually.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void transferStacks(stack<int> & s1, stack<int> & s2){
    if (s1.empty()){
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++){
            int element = s2.top();
            s1.push(element);
            s2.pop();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    int queries = 0;
    cin>>queries;

    stack <int> newestOnTop;
    stack <int> oldestOnTop;

    while (queries!=0){
        int type = 0;
        cin >> type;
        int input = 0;
        if (type == 1){ //enqueue
            cin>>input;
            newestOnTop.push(input);
        }
        else if (type == 2){ //dequeue
            transferStacks(newestOnTop, oldestOnTop);
            oldestOnTop.pop();
        }
        else if (type == 3){ //peek
            transferStacks(newestOnTop, oldestOnTop);
            cout<<oldestOnTop.top()<<endl;
        }
        queries--;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Segmentation Fault

Comment: What is the *input* that results in a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to believe that this code will copy `s2` to `s1`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++){
        int element = s2.top();
        s1.push(element);
        s2.pop();
    }
```

But it will not: if before the loop `s2` contains 3 elements, only the first 2 will be copied (and generally, only the first half will be copied).

In addition, your `transfer` function transfers *from* `s2` to `s1`, but the way you *call* it implies that you intended the *opposite*: to transfer from `s1` to `s2`. Current code would leave `oldestOnTop` empty, which will then result in a crash when you use `oldestOnTop.top()` or `oldestOnTop.pop()`.

Comment: Hey thank you! The two problems you've identified resolved my problem. I needed to use a constant value for s2.size() since its size is changing. Also I switched up oldestOnTop and newestOnTop, which was probably why it was causing the Segmentation Fault.

Comment: You should change the for loop into while(!s2.empty()) {...}

Comment: Yes good call, that way I don't have to worry about the size changing and can just pop without worry.